# Clean OSX (Mavericks) install: User folder / ACLs / .DocumentRevisions-V100/

Tags: macos, installation, permissions, acl

I want to do a clean install of OSX Mavericks and manually transfer user-files.

**Reasons:**

- I have migrated my User-Account over 3 or 4 releases and I want to make sure i don't carry old data or launch-agents and the like around.
- DiskUtility/Verify Disk tells me about a checksum-problem somewhere with my hard-drive for month and it's not possible to fix it in Repair Mode.

**My plan:**

- Copy everything onto a backup-disk (using TimeMachine)
- Create an Installer-USB-Stick, wipe the disk with DiskUtility and install.
- Recreate my settings.
- Copy over "regular files" like Documents, unmanaged Fotos, Videos etc. from the "raw" TimeMachine-disk.
- Copy over stand-alone applications, reinstall more complex stuff.

Up to this point I think I can just `chown` the files to belong to the new user (which is going to have a different id).

**Problem areas:**

- KeyChain: can be imported/exported which should pose no problem.
- necessary `Library/Application Support`-Folders: This is were it starts to get tricky. Are ACLs involved here? Probably…
- FileVersions: If I understand correctly, those are kept in `/.DocumentRevisions-V100`. Are user-Ids involved here?

**Further questions:**

- Can I somehow change the ACLs to reflect the new user-id?
- Should I forget about cleaning out my UserAccount and just do a clean-install to repair the disk and afterwards use the MigrationAssistant?
- Is it wrong to assume that I can `cp` or `rsync` from TimeMachine-Backup directly?
- What else could possible go wrong?

Comment: This seems like an awfully complicated way to me. Wouldn't it be much easier to just find out where there is wasted space? (ccleaner comes to mind)

Comment: Yeah, one reason is the 'inconsistent crosscheck' warning that DiskUtility reports for my boot-volume.

Comment: But what about plain restoring from time machine and then do the cleaning afterwards?